# Why can't Scrapy edit the page in the script?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a script for Scrapy that runs under the Scrapy Shell, but when I start it as a script with `scrapy runspider script.py` the following error occurs:

```
    2020-01-16 19:10:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://https//shop.palaceskateboards.com/collections/jackets/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 512, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 982, in startConnectionAttempts
    "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr)
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: https.
```

If I try it as a Scrapy Shell, it works. If I try it as a Scrapy Shell, it works. On other sites this error also occurs when I try it as a script. I use Scrapy in Python3.

Comment: well `http://https//shop.palaceskateboards.com` isnt a valid url

Comment: Thanks man, I missed it, it works now! :D